# According to Firebug, static files are only compressed when Fiddler is running - why?

Tags: iis, iis-6, compression, firebug, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET MVC site running in IIS 6.0 and want it to compress the static css and js files it serves. The site has a wildcard mapping so all requests (inc. extensionless URLs) go via aspnet_isapi.dll. Static content is held in the Content and Scripts folders.

I have carried out the following steps:

- Enabled HTTP compression for application files and static files in the IIS Console (Web Sites -> Service tab).
- Added a Web Service Extension named "HTTP Compression" referring to inetsrv\gzip.dll
- Edited MetaBase.xml to add css and js to the HcFileExtensions property of the gzip and deflate IIsCompressionScheme entries.
- Removed the wildcard mapping from the Content and Scripts folders (did so by temporarily making them subwebs, removed the wildcard map, reverted them back to ordinary folders). This should ensure IIS serves those files without ASP.NET getting involved.

The strange behaviour I now get is that, when Fiddler is running, it reports compressed file sizes for css and js, and Firebug concurs (e.g. 47.9KB for jquery-ui.min.js). But when I disable Fiddler and hit CTRL+F5, Firebug reports uncompressed sizes (194.2KB for jquery-ui.min.js) and unexpected Content-Type and Content-Length.

The request headers do not change, but it's interesting to look at the response headers.
With Fiddler running, Firebug reports (for jquery-ui.min.js):

```
Content-Length  49009
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding    gzip
Last-Modified   Wed, 26 Jan 2011 11:59:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Etag    "80cce07950bdcb1:a03"
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
x-ua-compatible IE=8
```

Without Fiddler:

```
Proxy-Authenticate  NTLM
Content-Length  415
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**Why is Content-Type now text/html? The Content-Length of 415 looks odd, it doesn't match the 194.2KB that Firebug reports as the size of the response. Various other headers are no longer present.**

For completeness, the request header is:

```
Host    my-windows-box
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Referer http://my-windows-box/site
Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=nbsb2hbkjdtcgjdntco25zqc
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the status code on the response in Firebug? My first guess is that it's a HTTP/401 and what you're seeing here is the authentication page that requests your NTLM credentials.

Comment: The status code is 200, and for a given file Fiddler reports a response size equal to the zipped file size (confirmed by zipping various js, css files in Windows Explorer).